# Aggregate values in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have a table in Oracle which consists of multiple columns as per below.

Im looking for a way of aggregating the values on this table to show Sum of Countries where Region is "Region name "

```
accnt  country  region  value
--------------------------------------
1        A       AS     20
1        B       AS     70
1        C       AF     10
2        D       NA     50
2        E       AS     40
2        F       AF     10
3        G       NA     30
3        H       AS     30
4        I       NA     50
4        J       NA     40
4        K       NA     20
```

how can i achieve this?

thanks for your help

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: What part is it you don't know how to solve: restrict your result to one region or get a column's sum? Both tasks seem very basic. Have you even tried it yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a particular region, you can do this:

```
select count(*) totalcountries, sum(value) as totalvalue
from tablename
where region = 'AS'
```

Result:

```
| totalcountries | totalvalue |
|----------------|------------|
|              4 |        160 |
```

For multiple regions, you can do this:

```
select count(*) as totalcountries, sum(value) as totalvalue
from test1
where region in ('AS','NA')
```

Result:

```
| totalcountries | totalvalue |
|----------------|------------|
|              9 |        350 |
```

To get information by region, you can do what Mureinik mentions

```
select region, count(*) as totalcountries, sum(value) as totalvalue
from test1
group by region
```

Result:

```
| region | totalcountries | totalvalue |
|--------|----------------|------------|
|     AF |              2 |         20 |
|     AS |              4 |        160 |
|     NA |              5 |        190 |
```

If you want to get information by region but only for a couple of regions, you could do this:

```
select region, count(*) as totalcountries, sum(value) as totalvalue
from test1
where region in ('AS', 'NA')
group by region;
```

Result:

```
| region | totalcountries | totalvalue |
|--------|----------------|------------|
|     AS |              4 |        160 |
|     NA |              5 |        190 |
```

Here's an example with MySQL; the same queries will work with Oracle. Since SQLFiddle wasn't working well with Oracle I chose to sample the information with MySQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/081c0/4

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm going to go with "Where region in ". that SQL Fiddle is great. the only issue here is that the values in the original table are coming from 3 different joins. Account, Country, Region . which all are link with Value table using ID. Region is linked to Country. will i be able to incorporate the select statement you sent right after i've done my joins. Perhaps using stored procedure? Thanks

Comment: Sounds great. To put closure to your question, please mark one of the answers as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions163.htm) function and group your results by the `region`:

```
SELECT   region, SUM(value)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY region
```